# Read spss file with Cyrillic into R

Tags: r, spss, cyrillic

I am trying to read several SPSS files into R that include `Cyrillic text`. All of the files are in `Cyrillic text`. When I read most of them into R, the console says "re-encoding from CP1251". However, when I read some of the files, also in `Cyrillic text`, it says "re-encoding from CP1252" which I think is a Latin script. The `CP1251` files read into R with no problem. However, the `CP1252` files become gibberish in R.  I’ve tried the `foreign`, `haven` and `hmisc` packages for reading in the SPSS files and none have worked. I've also tried including `reencode='utf-8'`. When I do this, the Cyrillic text all becomes NA. The problem occurs whether I'm working in R or RStudio.

```
x1<- read.spss("cp1251_file.sav", to.data.frame = T) #1251 file reads in fine

x2<- read.spss("cp1252_file.sav", to.data.frame = T) #1252 file becomes gibberish

x2<- read.spss("cp1252_file.sav", to.data.frame = T, reencode='utf-8') #Cyrillic text in CP1252 file becomes NA
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: for me it works for German umlaute (üäö) with a combination of the following: `options(encoding = "UTF-8");
spssfile <- as.data.set(spss.system.file('yourfiles.sav'));
spssfile <- Iconv(spssfile,from="UTF-8",to="UTF-8")`can you check those?

Comment: this question/answers may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136293/read-spss-file-into-r?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this and now I get an error when I try to convert to a dataframe. spssfile <- as.data.set(spss.system.file('file.sav', use.value.labels = FALSE));
spssfile <- Iconv(spssfile,from="UTF-8",to="UTF-8"); df<- as.data.frame(spssfile, stringsAsFactors=F); error: Error in as.factor(x) : Duplicate labels

Comment: Looks like it works if I tell R that the file is CP1251 even though it thinks it is CP1252. Thanks!:

'df <- spss.system.file("file.sav")
df <- Iconv(df,from="CP1251",to="UTF-8")
df1<-as.data.frame(as.data.set(df))'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works if I use the `memisc` package and I tell R that the file is CP1251 even though it thinks it is CP1252 when using read.spss. Thanks!:

`df <- spss.system.file("file.sav")
df <- Iconv(df,from="CP1251",to="UTF-8")
df1<-as.data.frame(as.data.set(df))`