# Why is my .sav data file being picked up on by read.spss function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, spss

I'm trying to load a .sav dataset into R. But I am getting the following error:

> Error in read.spss(file.choose(), to.data.frame = TRUE) :
> file 'C:\Users\H-Zah\OneDrive\Documents\UniQ\R work\Hamzah.sav' is not in any supported SPSS format

Any there any reasons why this might be happening?

Comment: You are going to have to provide something for people here like, say. a 2 line .sav file that produces the same error.

Comment: Take a look at [Read SPSS file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136293/read-spss-file-into-r). There are several other packages that have functions for importing SPSS files.